# My code returning incorrect values

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP code I run the following statement:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tb_services` WHERE tb_services.user_id = :var1 AND
(tb_services.user_id = :var1 OR tb_services.user_id = (SELECT subuser_owner_id FROM tb_users WHERE user_id = :var1))
AND tc_services.sub_id = :var2");
$stmt->bindParam(":var1", $_GET['var1']);
$stmt->bindParam(":var2", $_GET['var2']);
```

However doing `$stmt->rowCount()` returns `0`, but when I run this exact statement(filled with the same values that I'm inputting instead of the `:var1, :var2`) it finds the row perfectly.

`while($info = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`

The above is the code that is not running. As the return of the `rowCount()` is `0` and the while loop is not running, that just shows to me that it is for some reason not finding the row. If I input static values into the SQL statement, it works perfectly.

Comment: can you print stmt and make sure the values are inputting properly

Comment: @themerlinproject I wanted to do that but I don't know how to print it out with the values replaced.

Comment: Probably not a good question, but are using the `execute()` call before `rowCount()`?

Comment: Yes. This is the if statement: if($stmt->execute()) {
    echo $stmt->rowCount();

Comment: I'll add more information to my orginal post to clarify a few things

Comment: if($stmt->execute()) {
    echo $stmt->rowCount();
    
     while($info = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error. I was overlooking my code and saw the stupid mistake I made. For anyone out there that might experience a similar problem, the following MySQL statement:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tb_services` WHERE tb_services.user_id = :var1 AND
(tb_services.user_id = :var1 OR tb_services.user_id = (SELECT subuser_owner_id FROM     tb_users WHERE user_id = :var1))
AND tc_services.sub_id = :var2");
```

should be

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tb_services` WHERE(tb_services.user_id = :var1 OR     tb_services.user_id = (SELECT subuser_owner_id FROM     tb_users WHERE user_id = :var1))
AND tc_services.sub_id = :var2");
```

- Removing the first `tb_services.user_id = :var1` as that caused the error.